# ASP.Net and Web Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services

I have been searching for 4 days non stop. I am sleep deprived and going crazy. Can someone please help me or at least tell me what I'm doing wrong. This is my project
Develop a client web page app that uses the web service found at http://www.marksmerry.com/peanutbutter/WebService1.asmx.
The service generates a random number m
This service receives a guess , an integer between 1-100 inclusive. It returns a string:

- low   -  if the guess is lower than m
- equal – if the guess is correct
- high  - if the guess is higher  than m

I have referenced the web service but I'm lost at the syntax or something please help me! This is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using localhost;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        localhost.WebService1 ws1 = new WebService1();
        //What goes in this area. I have been searching and have tried all kinds of combination all have resulted in build errors


    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you wrote question title :)

Comment: Are you sure that you properly added a web reference to that WS? Using "localhost" indicates that you are running the WS locally? Is that supposed to be like that?

Comment: I just choose local host because msdn was using it.

Comment: So I am supposed to send a "guess" to the service and receive a "high" "low" or "equal". If I look at this logic this is what I can gather, my textbox1 is the string I'm supposed to send to the service where it compares it against the ==,>,< clauses where it returns the output. I'm having issue with the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

type ws1. and a list of methods will appear.

any service methods that were discovered by visual studio when you referenced the 'peanutbutter' webservice will be available to call on the proxy class (called WebService1 in your code example).

Comment: Methods would be considered this?

Comment: I want to understand the logic behind this. so the following is the method in the web service is what is located under that [WebMethod] tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you just type the url in the browser, it wil show you what methods it has.

http://www.marksmerry.com/peanutbutter/WebService1.asmx

I can see a web method Guess which takes an int.

As per your code, You can call it via

```
string result = ws1.Guess(10); // or input
```

Comment: It says can not convert int to string

Comment: That's because method "Guess" returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

`string result = ws1.Guess(42);`

Answer (score 0):

When you added the reference you should have got the chance to give it a name. It's only semantics but it might be better to give it a different name from localhost.

Previous commentators have made good suggestions so I'd follow them.

Only thing I'd suggest is this.

string result = ws1.Guess("10");   *//EDIT: this is wrong  of course. It takes an int.*

I did some work this morning using a web service.

myCoService.Service1 v24 = new myCoService.Service1();

System.Xml.XmlNode doc = v24.CreateSite(newSiteName);

Should be as simple as that.

If it isn't I'd have a look again at how you set up your web reference. Also please let us know what NET framework you are using.

I added a web Reference to a test project and a button on a page which fires this event.

```
    protected void PeanutGuess_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        PeanutButter.WebService1 pb = new PeanutButter.WebService1();

        string response = pb.Guess(10);

        lblResult.Text = string.Format("Response for 10 is " + response);
    }
```

This works fine for me. I'm using VS2010 and the project uses Net Framework 3.5

Comment: .net framework is 4.0. This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so very much. As a second part of the project I have a label that tells the number of guesses you have made how would I go about changing the lbltry to the number of times I guess?

Comment: If you look at the code I've put in the PeanutGuess_click event above, you'll see that I update the text property of a label. That should be all you need to do. Get a variable, increment it for each guess, and write that to the label.